# When a control becomes invisible, how can I move focus to the next sibling instead of the parent?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In WPF it appears that by default when a focused control becomes invisible, focus changes to the next focusable parent container. Is there a generic way to move focus to the next focusable sibling control instead? For instance, given this contrived example:

```
<StackPanel Focusable="True">
        <Button Height="30" Width="150" Click="Button_Click">First</Button>
        <Button Height="30" Width="150">Second</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

and this event handler to hide the first button:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((Button) sender).Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

If you tab to the first button and press Enter, the StackPanel receives focus. I want the second button to receive focus.

I'm hoping for a generic solution (as opposed to setting focus to a particular element via code behind) because I have several places in my app where this is an issue for keyboard navigation.

Comment: Does [FocusManager.IsFocusScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.isfocusscope(v=vs.110).aspx) on the StackPanel have that effect?

Comment: Yes, it acts the same way. If the immediate parent has `IsFocusScope` set false, then WPF seems to just walk up the tree to find the first focusable parent control and then focuses that. (In reality, these containers are user controls or ListBoxes, things that could legitimately receive focus, not StackPanels.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FocusManager.SetFocusedElement`https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.setfocusedelement(v=vs.110).aspx can be used to set the logical focus to a specific element.

```
FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(focusScope1, button2);
```

You need to have the current focus scope for this.

This can be done from XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="FocusButton" TargetType="StackPanel">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=button1, Path=IsVisible}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=button2}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The logical focus is not the same as the keyboard focus - [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: This is helpful. It's unfortunately not an ideal "general case" setting I can apply, but it's enough to get me past my current issue. Thanks!